# pdf.js issue in ipad with more pages

Tags: javascript, pdf.js

I am using pdf.js for my application and my browser is closing automatically while trying to open long PDF files (more than 15 pages) on iPad.

Is there any fix for this?

Comment: pdf.js is very memory intensive, your browser probably ran out of memory while loading the pdf.